# get string combination probability from 3 list of strings in c#

Tags: c#, list

i need a short logic to buid the collection of string from 3 lists. ex.
List 1 : APAC,America, Europe
List 1 : US, UK, India
Liat 2 :British, English,Hindi

So i need collection os strings :
APAC/US/British
APAC/US/English
APAc/US/Hindi
APAC/UK/British
APAC/UK/English
APAc/UK/Hindi
APAC/Europe/British
APAC/Europe/English
APAc/Europe/Hindi

America/US/British
America/US/English
America/US/Hindi
America/UK/British
America/UK/English
America/UK/Hindi
America/Europe/British
America/Europe/English
America/Europe/Hindi

and so on...for individual...

in c#

OOPS... Forgot to tell you guys... if list1 get empty then combination should continue with List2 and list 3
**Edited: Chaged Scenario**
right now i am confuse...: I am having List>
I don't know haw many List
I somehow need to prepare the strings, based on index like

```
string str = List<Lits<string>(0)> +List<Lits<string>(1)>+ List<Lits<string>(2)>...
```

how to do this...

Comment: where does "probability" fit into this, and: what have you tried? it sounds to me like a nested loop would have this sorted in no time...

Comment: @Darth unless we consider nC1 from the first set, nC1 from the second set... ;p (but yes, I agree...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like homework to me, but anyway...

```
ICollection<String> result = new List<String>();

foreach (String region in list1)
{
    foreach (String state in list2)
    {
        foreach (String lang in list3)
        {
            result.Add(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", region, state, lang));
        }
    }
}

// Use result...
```

Answer (score 0):

3 foreach would do it for you.

```
foreach(var c1 in list1)
{

   foreach(var c2  in list2)
   {

     foreach(var c3 in list3)
     {
        Console.write(c1+c2+c3);
     }
   }

}
```

here is a linq solution:

```
var res = from l1 in list1
          from l2 in list2
          from l3 in list3
          select new {Item = l1+l2+l3};
```

Comment: @Derth, and if here list 1 get empty then ? it should continue with List2 and list 3 ... there also a case if List 2 is empty...then again , hang here...